# How to pass User.username in reverse function?

Tags: django, django-views

Its showing following error on url page-

> Reverse for  'views.demo_function'  with arguments  '()'  and keyword
>   arguments  '{'user_name': u'demo_user'}'  not found.  0 pattern(s)
>   tried: []

Here is my 'demo_function' in views:

```
def demo_function(request, user_name):

    context = RequestContext(request)

    profile_dict = {'username':user_name}

    render_to_response('project1/profile.html', profile_dict, context)
```

Here is my function which has "reverse" method:

```
def user_login(request):

    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)


        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                #profile(request, username)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('views.demo_function', kwargs={'user_name':username}))
            ...
            ...
```

Comment: What does your relevant code in `urls.py` look like?

Comment: url(r'^home/profile/(?P<user_name>\w+)/$', views.demo_function, name='profile'),
url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),

Comment: try use the name of the url in the reverse : return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile', kwargs={'user_name':username}))

Comment: not working, apparently username is not string. what does User.username returns ?

Comment: cud u paste entire code inside urls.py???

Comment: urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^home/profile/(?P<user_name>\w+)/$', views.demo_function, name='profile'), url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login')
)

Comment: Try to debug and put a breaking point where you assign the username to see what it contains.

Comment: It is working with 'HttpResponse()', but not with 'render_to_response()'.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the user object instead of using post variable :

```
def user_login(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)


        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                #profile(request, username)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile', kwargs={'user_name': user.username}))
```

Simple test, did you try to access this url with a valid user (not reverse it) :

```
/home/profile/demo_user/
```

Can you access the page ?

Can you edit the post and add your urls files ? (project and app urls)

Comment: It is working with 'HttpResponse()', but not with 'render_to_response()'.

Comment: error : "**The view demo_app.views.demo_function didn't return an HttpResponse object.**"

Comment: you forgot the return before render_to_response : **return** render_to_response('project1/profile.html', profile_dict, context)